# Deserialize JSON Object using VB.Net

Tags: c#, .net, json, vb.net

I have a VB.Net windows application that makes a RESTful WS call to a C# web application that uses JSON.Net to serialize the results that are contained in a 
`Dictionary<String, String>`.

The response from the C# web application comes back as a JSON string that looks like this:

```
"{"8bf370f3-d258-40d3-a659-063db90f5291":"String1","5a0248de-7139-44ba-991b-072d598ff9ab":"String2"}"
```

On the VB.Net Side, I use JSON.Net to try to Deserialize the response and I get this error:

```
Error converting value 
"{"8bf370f3-d258-40d3-a659-063db90f5291":"String1","5a0248de-7139-44ba-991b-072d598ff9ab":"String2"}"
to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`
2[System.String,System.String]'. Path '', line 1, position 1383.
```

Here is the VB.Net code:

```
..
..
reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

' Console application output 

Dim responseStr As String = reader.ReadToEnd
'MsgBox(responseStr)

'Error occurs on the next line.
Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, String) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(responseStr)

Dim pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)
For Each pair In dict
    MsgBox("Key: " & pair.Key.ToString & " Value: " & pair.Value)
Next
..
..
```

I have tried using "Object" as the type instead of String, and I get the same error.  I can't see anything wrong with the JSON itself or anything wrong with the deserialization method call so i'm at a loss. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The fact that json is failing at position 1383 suggests that the actual json is longer than what you've posted. Can you post the full json body that is causing the failure?

Comment: Are you sure about the content of `responseStr`? Does the following fail in your code: `Dim dictionary As Dictionary(Of String, String) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))("{""8bf370f3-d258-40d3-a659-063db90f5291"":""String1"",""5a0248de-7139-44ba-991b-072d598ff9ab"":""String2""}")`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you JSON needs to look like this:

```
[{"8bf370f3-d258-40d3-a659-063db90f5291":"String1"},{"5a0248de-7139-44ba-991b-072d598ff9ab":"String2"}]
```

Dictionary is a collection of key/value pairs and you have no collection of items in your JSON only a single object with 4 properties.

Comment: It is object with 2 properties, and yes, it can be deserialized into dictionary - see **Deserializing Dictionaries** at [Serializing Collections](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingCollections.htm)